# cron jobs not working

Tags: wordpress, cron

Can someone help with debugging why cron jobs aren't activated on my site?

When looking at civiCRM system status under Set-up Cron it says

> No cron runs have been recorded.
> A cron job is required to execute scheduled jobs automatically.

In the Settings - Scheduled jobs, the Update Membership Statuses (Daily) is activated (along with a few others) with no added parameters but the pop-up window still claims that there is none recorded.

I can execute the job manually but that kind of defeats the purpose.

My CMS guy says that cron works every six hours as per instructions in the docs (picture).
[image: cron-jobs]

How do I solve this?

Version of Wordpress it's on is 5.9.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the http method for calling cron, the [docs detail](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#http) That you will need to use wget or curl to pass parameters to the request.   The wget will look similiar to:

`wget -O - -q -t 1 'https://example.org/<CONTENT-DIR>/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=<username>&pass=<password>&key=<site-key>`

I would strongly recommend the [wp-cli method in the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#wp-cli) as that will be much more reliable.

Comment: Okay, will forward that to the CMS guy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the same url internally with PHP. I found this to be more reliable than an external https call.

Here is an example from the CiviCRM docs.
php /your/directory/structure/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u user -p password -e Job -a execute